# Telnet from telnet session in python

Tags: python, telnet

Is it possible to telnet to a server and from there telnet to another server in python?
Since there is a controller which I telnet into using a username and password, and from the controller command line I need to login as root to run linux command. How would I do that using python?

I use the `telentlib` to login into router controller but from the router controller I need to log in again to get into shell. Is this possible using python?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: Using python; telnet to controller, then from the controller telnet to a server..?

Comment: I think you would have to command router session to open an additional telnet to the desired pc. This means you have two telnet sessions,.. pc1->router and router->pc2, where pc1 sends commands to control the router->pc2 connection

Comment: Telnet to controller and once I login to controller then I need to login as root to see bash shell prompt

Answer (score 1):

Just checked it with the hardware I have in hand & telnetlib. Saw no problem.
When you are connected to the first device just send all the necessary commands using `telnet.write('cmd')`. It may be `sudo su\n`, `telnet 192.168.0.2\n` or whatever else. Telnetlib keeps in mind only its own telnet connection, all secondary connections are handled by the corresponding controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using expect (there should be a python binding); basically, what I think you want to do is:

1. From your python script, use telnetlib to connect to server A (pass in username/password).
2. Within this "socket", send the remaining commands, e.g. "telnet serverB" and use expect (or some other mechanism) to check that you get back the expected "User:" prompt; if so, send user and then password and then whatever commands, and otherwise handle errors.

This should be very much doable and is fairly common with older stuff that doesn't support a cleaner API.

Comment: Thanks ! this idea also I have tried but issue is when I loin into root from controller and run command then output of command is not returned by tn.read_all() . It gives File "/usr/lib/python2.4/telnetlib.py", line 521, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
error

Comment: Can you include your code (sans any passwords / sensitive ips /etc.) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.write) to issue the sudo command.

```
tn.write("sudo\n")
```

You could also use [`read_until()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until) to help with the credentials.

```
tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
```

Comment: This I have used it.
But this only takes me to controller console and from there I need to login again as root and provide password to access linux shell>
I tried using write but once main controller session starts, and if i try to login to root using write, it hangs there